# Reference of pointer and left shift operator

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, operator-overloading, pass-by-reference

I have redefined the << operator and I want it to take a reference of pointer.

```
class foo
{
    foo();
    virtual ~foo();

    void operator << (BaseService*& iRight);
}
```

Somewhere in the code, having a foo instance, and a service which is a specialization of the BaseService class I do :

```
Service* service_pointer = new Service();
foo_instance << service_pointer;
```

But I get this error :
   error: no match for 'operator<<'in 'foo_instance << service_pointer'
   note: candidates are: void foo::operator<<(BaseService*&)

Nothing changes if I dynamic_cast my service_pointer to BaseService

```
Service* service_pointer = new Service();
foo_instance << dynamic_cast<BaseService*>(service_pointer);
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first version does not work because you can't pass in a reference to a pointer to a subtype and rightly so: What if the implementation of `operator<<` made the pointer point to an instance `MyService` (which is a subclass of `BaseService`, but not of `Service`)? Clearly it would be illegal for a `Service*` to point to a `MyService`. So passing in a `Service*` is not allowed.

The second version is not allowed because `dynamic_cast` does not return an l-value, so you can't pass it as a non-const reference.

The only thing you can do is define another variable of type `BaseService*` and pass that as an argument to `<<`. If `<<` then reassigns the pointer, that change will be visible for the newly created variable only and not affect `ServicePointer`.

That being said (and not knowing your use case) I have to advice you that having `operator<<` take a non-const reference to anything as its right operand strikes me as bad practice. You wouldn't usually expect `<<` to modify it's right operand.

Answer (score 1):

Just because `Service *` type is convertible to `BaseService *` type does not in any way mean that `Service *&` type is convertible to `BaseService *&` type. It isn't. This is why your first call does not compile.

Trying to use `dynamic_cast` (or any other non-hacking cast) will not help. The result of such cast is not an lvalue. And you cannot bind a non-const reference to something that is not an lvalue. This is why your second call does not compile.

If you really want your operator to accept specifically `BaseService *&`, then you are limited to performing a manual pre-conversion of `Service *` to an *lvalue* of type `BaseService *` (i.e. to an explicit pointer object) and then calling the operator with that lvalue

```
Service* service_pointer = new Service();
BaseService* base_service_pointer = service_pointer;
foo_instance << base_service_pointer;
```

Your calls to operator `<<` will compile if you change the declaration if the operator to

```
void operator <<(BaseService* const& iRight);
```

but whether you can do it or not depends on your intent. Why are you trying to pass a pointer by reference?

Comment: I'm trying to pass a pointer by reference because my foo class contains a list of services, and potentially, the service added with the << operator will be merged (if possible) with an existing service.In that case the service_pointer will be deleted and I wanted to avoid any issue if the caller will use it again by re-assigning it to the service were the new service has been merged to.

Answer (score 0):

You have to actually define a `BaseService` pointer variable.

```
Service* service_pointer = new Service();
BaseService* base_service_pointer = dynamic_cast<BaseService*>(service_pointer);
foo_instance << base_service_pointer;
```

As you want to take a reference to the pointer, it cannot be an rvalue.

Also note that the `dynamic_cast<>` it not necessary here. A `static_cast<>` would to the trick. Even better, use a simple assignment from `service_pointer` to `base_service_pointer`!

Answer (score 0):

This can't possibly work because reference is non-const, so you can change the pointer value in foo::operator<<. Consider the following example:

```
class Service1 : BaseService
{
};

class Service2 : BaseService
{
};

void foo::operator << (BaseService*& iRight)
{
    // ok, iRight is a reference to BaseService*
    // so we can assign Service2* to it, can't we?
    iRight = new Service2();
}

Service1* service_pointer = new Service1();
foo_instance << service_pointer; // oops...
```